# PHP: ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre bindParam() y bindValue() en PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

En realidad no tengo claro ¿cuál es la diferencia entre los métodos `bindParam()` y `bindValue()` a la hora de hacer consultas a mi base de datos usando PDO.

Me gustaría entender la diferencia, si es posible con algún ejemplo ilustrativo.

Y, sin entrar en el terreno de las opiniones, saber si cada uno existe para un uso específico o si por el contrario se pueden usar indistintamente.

Comment: Acabo de leer que pides ejemplo. Si no te basta con mi explicación dímelo y te pongo un ejemplo de cada uno y su respuesta a modificaciones posteriores.

Comment: @OscarGarcia Gracias. Sí, creo que se entendería mejor con un ejemplo. Mi confusión vino también al haber leído que el comportamiento entre uno y otro no era igual por ejemplo al tratar los valores nulos. O que bindValue no era tan eficaz como bindParam a la hora de prevenir inyección SQL (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413326/confusion-between-bindvalue-and-bindparam)

Comment: Creo que esa respuesta te está confundiendo. Prácticamente te explican lo mismo que yo te he explicado en cuanto al comportamiento (con un ejemplo que prácticamente copiaré/pegaré), pero te explican que ninguno de los dos interpreta el significado SEMÁNTICO de un % o _ como comodín, agregando que AMBOS protegen por igual contra inyección. Es decir, que eso último es exactamente igual en ambos y no es nada de lo que preocuparse.

Comment: Agregada la edición

Answer (score 24, accepted):

La propia documentación de PHP te explica la diferencia en la página de [`PDOStatement::bindParam()`](http://php.net/pdostatement.bindparam):

> A diferencia de
>   `PDOStatement::bindValue()`, la variable es vinculada como una
>   referencia y solamente será evaluada en el momento en el que se llame
>   a `PDOStatement::execute()`.

Es decir, en `PDOStatement::bindParam()` se pasa una referencia de la variable (un "puntero") de manera que si cambias su valor antes de un `execute()`, éste hará la sustitución con el valor que tengan dichas variables en el instante de llamar al `execute()`, teniendo en cuenta esas últimas modificaciones.

En `PDOStatement::bindValue()` se asigna el valor que tenga en ese momento la variable y aunque ésta cambie a lo largo de varias ejecuciones de `execute()` la sustitución permanece invariable.

Ambas protegen por igual de inyección SQL y tienen exactamente el mismo comportamiento interno una vez resueltas las sustituciones.

---

**Ejemplo ilustrativo con [`PDOStatement::bindValue()`](http://php.net/pdostatement.bindvalue):**

```
$consulta = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM `tabla` WHERE ejemplo = :ejemplo');

$ejemplo = 'un_ejemplo';
/* Aquí es donde se tiene en cuenta el valor de $ejemplo: un_ejemplo */
$consulta->bindValue(':ejemplo', $ejemplo);
$ejemplo = 'otro_ejemplo';

$consulta->execute();
```

La consulta ejecuta `SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE ejemplo = 'un_ejemplo'` porque se fija el valor de `:ejemplo` con el contenido de la variable `$ejemplo`, que es "un_ejemplo" en el momento de ejecutarse [`bindValue()`](http://php.net/pdostatement.bindvalue).

**Ejemplo ilustrativo con [`PDOStatement::bindParam()`](http://php.net/pdostatement.bindparam):**

```
$consulta = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM `tabla` WHERE ejemplo = :ejemplo');

$ejemplo = 'un_ejemplo';
$consulta->bindParam(':ejemplo', $ejemplo);
$ejemplo = 'otro_ejemplo';

/* Aquí es donde se tiene en cuenta el valor de $ejemplo: otro_ejemplo */
$consulta->execute();
```

La consulta ejecuta `SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE ejemplo = 'otro_ejemplo'` porque NO se fija el valor de `:ejemplo` como el en ejemplo anterior, si no que obtiene el valor de la variable `$ejemplo` cuando se ejecuta `execute()`, y en ese momento el valor es "otro_ejemplo".

---

**Ejemplo ilustrativo con [`PDOStatement::bindValue()`](http://php.net/pdostatement.bindvalue) (2):**

```
$consulta = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO tabla (valor) VALUES (:valor)');

$ejemplo = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ];
foreach ($ejemplo as $valor) {
  $consulta->bindValue(':valor', $valor);
  $consulta->execute();
}
```

Por cada iteración tenemos que hacer un `bindValue()` y un `execute()`.

**Ejemplo ilustrativo con [`PDOStatement::bindParam()`](http://php.net/pdostatement.bindparam) (2):**

```
$consulta = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO tabla (valor) VALUES (:valor)');

$ejemplo = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ];
$valor = ''; /* No es necesario, pero es ilustrativo */
$consulta->bindParam(':valor', $valor);
foreach ($ejemplo as $valor) {
  $consulta->execute();
}
```

Como tenemos guardada la referencia a la variable `$valor` no es necesario volver a llamar a `bindParam()` antes de cada `execute()`.

Comment: +1 Excelente respuesta. Para que sea completa y aceptada creo que le faltaría indicar, si es posible, por qué existen uno y otro... imagino que se debe a que hay casos en los que conviene usar `bindParam()` y otros en los que sería mejor usar `bindValue()`. Con esa pequeña explicación podría dar la respuesta por aceptada. Gracias.

Comment: Ya me pediste un ejemplo ilustrativo. Voy a ponerte otro adicional, supongo que con eso te tendrías que hacer una idea de su uso y en qué casos te viene mejor usar uno u otro.

Comment: @OscarGarcia En el primer ejemplo el valor de la sentencia tomara "un_ejemplo" pero colocas "ejemplo" corrigelo. /// La consulta ejecuta SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE ejemplo = 'ejemplo' AQUI

Comment: Siéntete libre de editar mi respuesta siempre que quieras para corregir este tipo de errores :) voy a editarlo. Gracias por el aviso (cosas del copy/paste ;).

Comment: Ya he puesto varios ejemplos y casos de uso, ¿falta algo para completar la respuesta?

Comment: ¡Excelente! Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: Que excelente respuesta! Gracias ;)

Comment: Excelente respuesta, ahora veo el porque me salía otro valor. Gracias por la explicación.

Answer (score 0):

**Con BindParam solo puedes pasar variables 
y con BindValue puedes pasar Objetos**

```
    public function NuevoProyecto($Proyectos){
    try {
        $sql="INSERT INTO proyectos( titulo, cliente, descripcion, alias) VALUES (:titulo,:cliente,:descripcion,:imgcliente:,:fecha,:alias)";
        $con = new conexion();
        $sentencia = $con->getCon()->prepare($sql);     
        $sentencia ->bindValue(":titulo", $Proyectos->getTitulo());
        $sentencia ->bindValue(":cliente",$Proyectos->getCliente());
        $sentencia ->bindValue(":descripcion",$Proyectos->getDescripcion());
        $sentencia ->bindValue(":imgcliente",$Proyectos->setImgCliente());
        $sentencia ->bindValue(":fecha",$Proyectos->setFecha());
        $sentencia ->bindValue(":alias",$Proyectos->getAlias());
        $Exec = $sentencia -> execute();
        if ($Exec) {
            echo "Se agrego con exito";
        }else{
            echo "Ocurrio un error con la insersion";
        }
    } catch (Exception $E) {
        echo "hubo un error en Nuevo Proyecto" . $E->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que "puedes pasar objetos"? En tu caso parece que estás pasando cadenas de caracteres. Al ser una llamada a una función no es posible obtener la referencia (puntero) que requiere `bindParam()`. Pero es porque no se puede obtener una referencia al resultado de una llamada a una función (o método de clase, como es tu caso), no por "pasar objetos".