# ¿Esta protegido mi nuevo código de inyecciones sql y que función tiene prepare y bindvalue en PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, seguridad

Hola a todos soy nuevo en PHP, agradecería me explicaran este código que encontré para extraer la información de un form en html e insertarla en una base de datos por medio de PHP, solo cambie parámetros el único cambio que hice fue agregarle el bindvalue, porque escuche que sirve para prevenir la inyección sql, funciona pero me gustaría saber si es seguro para implementarlo en una empresa. Gracias a esta comunidad por su paciencia ha.

```
                <?php
// Get POST data

$cliente = ($_POST['cliente']);
$nombre_contacto= ($_POST['nombre_contacto']);
$email_comprador = ($_POST['email_comprador']);
$email_calidad = ($_POST['email_calidad']);

try {
    // Connect to db

    include_once 'resource/Database.php';


    // Set SQL
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO clientes (cliente, nombre_contacto, email_comprador, email_calidad) VALUES (:cliente, :nombre_contacto, :email_comprador, :email_calidad)';
    // Prepare query
    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindValue(":cliente",$cliente);
$query->bindValue(":nombre_contacto",$nombre_contacto);
    $query->bindValue(":email_comprador",$email_comprador);
$query->bindValue(":email_calidad",$email_calidad);

    // Execute query
    $query->execute(array(':cliente' => $cliente, ':nombre_contacto' => $nombre_contacto, ':email_comprador' => $email_comprador, ':email_calidad' => $email_calidad));
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}





?>
```

Por cierto no coloque este codigo y aun asi me inserta los datos deberia ponerselo?

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
```

Comment: Quizás podrás encontrar tu respuesta aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%c3%b3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%c3%b3n-sql-en-php y tu segunda duda `if(isset($_POST["submit"])){` si que lo implementaría, ya que estas diciendo si está definido tu formulario y no es `NULL` insértame los datos en caso contrario no entra en tu bucle `if`. Saludos.

Comment: Tu código es seguro. Pero debes saber que en PDO puedes pasar los valores en el `execute`, mediante un array... tal y como lo estás haciendo: **`$query->execute(array(':cliente' => $cliente, ':nombre_contacto' => $nombre_contacto, ':email_comprador' => $email_comprador, ':email_calidad' => $email_calidad));`**, haciendo esto, los `bindValue` no son necesarios y el código sigue siendo seguro, porque la prevención contra la Inyección SQL lo que te dice es que no pases variables externas en la consulta misma, sino aparte. En cuanto al `isset`, se recomienda tener control de la variables.

Answer (score 0):

el código `if(isset($_POST["submit"])){`

Indica que solo se pueda acceder al archivo o función, si ha sido mediante un POST Request, es decir que si alguien intenta acceder "facilmente" no podría, no al menos por un GET Request, por lo tanto es importante poner esa línea.

Además podrías usar http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.quote.php si querés un poco mas de seguridad.

Y leer la diferencia: [PHP: ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre bindParam() y bindValue() en PDO?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59971/php-cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-bindparam-y-bindvalue-en-pdo)