# por que falla la sentencia con PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Estoy haciendo una sentencia con PDO en PHP y ocurre un error al asignar los valores.

```
$request = 
[
   'lang'  =>  ['value'=>'es','type'=>PDO::PARAM_STR, 'length'=>2],
   'page'  =>  ['value'=>'home','type'=>PDO::PARAM_STR, 'length'=>null]
];

foreach ($request as $key => $value) 
{   
   $_value = $request[$key]['value'];
   $_type  = $request[$key]['type'];
   $_len   = $request[$key]['length'];


   // BindParam
   if($_len == null)
      $beforeQuery ->bindParam( $key, $_value ,$_type );
   else
      $beforeQuery ->bindParam( $key, $_value, $_type, $_len );

   // BindValue            
   $beforeQuery ->bindValue( ':'.$key, $_value ,$_type );


 }
```

#### Sentencia

`SELECT * FROM page WHERE lang_id=:lang AND page=:page`

#### Debug

Con BindParam me da este resultado que no es el correcto pero,

`SELECT * FROM interface WHERE lang='home' AND page='home'`

con BindValue si me hace la sentencia correctamente.

`SELECT * FROM interface WHERE lang='es' AND page='home'`

Comment: Creo que el tema esta en la diferencia entre `bindParam` y `bindValue`. Tienes esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/59972/74303) que lo explica bastante bien y quizas te puede echar una mano

Comment: Añade el error que te esta soltando. y el momento en el que ejecutas el la sentencia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando usas `bindParam` la variable que le pasas como segundo argumento es una referencia. Luego tú estás ejecutando dos iteraciones. En la primera le dices

```
$key = 'lang';
$_value = 'es';
$_type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
$beforeQuery ->bindParam( $key, $_value ,$_type );
```

En la segunda:

```
$key = 'page';
$_value = 'home';
$_type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
$beforeQuery ->bindParam( $key, $_value ,$_type );
```

Para PDO, al momento de ejecutar, y recién entonces, evalúa el valor del segundo parámetro (la variable $_value), y a esa altura, **el valor de $_value es el último definido dentro del bucle**, o sea `home`.

Lo correcto sería hacer, en cada iteración:

```
$beforeQuery ->bindValue( ':'.$key, $_value ,$_type );
```

Pero también debiera resultar si pasas el valor por referencia (`&$value`):

```
foreach ($request as $key => &$value) {  
     $beforeQuery ->bindParam( ':'.$key, $value['value'] ,$value['type'] );
}
```

¿Qué utilidad podría tener entonces `bindParam` si en este ejemplo lo más limpio sería usar `bindValue`?

La respuesta es que tendría sentido usarla para un `$statement->execute(...)`

```
$_value='cualquier cosa';

$beforeQuery->bindParam('id', $_value, PDO::PARAM_STR);

foreach($request as $key => $value) {
   $_value = $value['valor'];
   $result = $beforeQuery->execute();
   .. haces algo con result ...
}
```

Y eso funciona porque es el `execute` el que evalúa la variable, mientras que el `bindParam` no evalúa sino que establece un vínculo `lazy`.