# Cómo actualizar datos en la base de datos utilizando consultas preparadas

Tags: php, php7

He editado el código añadiendo medio lo que entiendo, estoy usando *mysqli* el código funciona bien, me gustaría saber si hace falta añadirle algo para que la consulta preparada quede bien.

```js
$email = $POST['email'];

$row = "UPDATE $users SET token = 'esto' WHERE email = ?";

if ($set = mysqli_prepare($base, $row)) {

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($set, "s", $email);

mysqli_stmt_execute($set);

}


if ($row) {

echo "Editado";

} else {

echo "Error";

}
```

Comment: Creo que conviene aclarar en la pregunta qué API estás usando (mysqli, PDO...), pues las consultas preparadas son distintas según la API. Indica también lo que has investigado/intentado y qué no entiendes de eso. La documentación del Manual de PHP sobre las consultas preparadas es bastante clara. En tu pregunta no aparece ningún esfuerzo por lograr algo relativamente fácil y sobre lo cual existe abundante documentación con ejemplos prácticos.

Comment: @A.Cedano He editado la pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Puedes realizarlo con [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php), utilizando la misma consulta que indicas:

```
$pdo = new PDO(...); //Datos de la conexión

$query = "UPDATE tabla SET data = ? WHERE email = ?";

$data = 0;
$email = "mail@mail.com";

$smt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$upd = $smt->execute(array($data,$email));
if ($upd) echo "Actualizando...";
else echo "Error al actualizar...";
```

Lo mismo utilizando [PDOStatement::bindValue](https://www.php.net/pdostatement.bindvalue):

```
$pdo = new PDO(...); //Datos de la conexión

$query = "UPDATE tabla SET data = :data WHERE email = :email";

$data = 0;
$email = "mail@mail.com";

$smt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$smt->bindValue(':data', $data);
$smt->bindValue(':email', $email);
$upd = $smt->execute();

if ($upd) echo "Actualizando...";
else echo "Error al actualizar...";
```

También puedes utilizar [PDOStatement::bindParam](https://www.php.net/pdostatement.bindparam) y en [esta entrada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59971/php-cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-bindparam-y-bindvalue-en-pdo/59972) está explicada la diferencia bindParam y bindValue.

Answer (score 1):

La consulta preparada en sí misma está bien. Sin embargo, yo mejoraría el código en tres aspectos:

1. Verificar que realmente hay un valor en el POST.
2. No estás evaluando la variable adecuada. En tu código `$row` sería una cadena con la consulta SQL, no representa para nada el objeto statement ni la ejecución de la consulta preparada, las cuales deberían ser evaluadas si quieres escribir un código robusto. Por lo demás, `$row` no parece ser un nombre adecuado para una instrucción SQL. Considera siempre dar a las variables nombres que indiquen su sentido.
3. Determinar si realmente se actualizaron filas, revisando la propiedad `affected_rows`  de `mysqli`, que es el único indicador seguro para tales fines, porque en algunos escenarios la ejecución puede ser `true`, pero no actualizar nada (por ejemplo si el criterio del `WHERE` no se cumple o si intentas actualizar la columna con el mismo valor que ya tiene).

El código quedaría así:

```
/*
   Si tienes PHP 5 o anterior 
   debes cambiar esta línea por esto: 
   $email = !empty($POST['email']) ? $POST['email'] : NULL;
*/   
   $email = $POST['email'] ?? NULL;

if($email) {  
    $sql = "UPDATE $users SET token = 'esto' WHERE email = ?";   
    if ($set = mysqli_prepare($base, $sql)) {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($set, "s", $email);
        if( mysqli_stmt_execute($set) ) {
            printf( "Se actualizaron %d filas",mysqli_affected_rows($base) );
        } else {
            # En producción sustituir mysqli_error por mensajes personalizados
            printf( "Error ejecutando la consulta: %s", mysqli_error($base) );
        }       
    } else {
        # En producción sustituir mysqli_error por mensajes personalizados
        printf( "Error preparando la consulta: %s", mysqli_error($base) );
    }
} else {
    echo "No se posteó un email";
}
```

Finalmente, te recomendaría migrar ya todo tu código   `mysqli` al estilo orientado a objetos. Es más claro, menos verboso y menos propenso a errores.