# Actualizar campo con valor variante

Tags: php

Tengo una tabla de trabajo, uno de los campos es un flg, lo que quiero es numerar a partir del número 1 hasta donde se necesite en el campo corr (inicialmente está vacío).
Tengo una clase llamada `numerador()`. Con esto quiero numerar cada registro incrementando la variable $num.
Pero no sé qué poner en el `while`.

```
$bd = new ConectaDB();
$sql = "UPDATE temporal SET corr = :num WHERE flg = 'X'";
$num = 0;

while(  ) {
    $num++;
    $stmt = $bd->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':num', $num, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

**ACTUALIZACION:** Este es el código que estoy probando, pero graba el mismo valor a todos los registros cumplan la condición o no. Les pone el número de registros que cumplen la condición.

```
$bd = new ConexionDB();
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM temporal WHERE flg = 'X'";
$stmt1 = $bd->prepare($sql1);
$stmt1->execute();

$sql2 = "UPDATE temporal SET corr = :num";
$stmt2 = $bd->prepare($sql2);
$num = 0;

while($row = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
    $num++;
    $stmt2->bindValue(':num', $num, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt2->execute();
}
```

Y esta es la estructura de mi tabla `temporal`.

```
CREATE TABLE `temporal` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `cod` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `nom` varchar(35) DEFAULT NULL,
  `flg` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `corr` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: *Quiero numerar desde el 1 todos los registros que cumplan con una condición*. Pues debes **seleccionar** esos registros, y a continuación hacer el `UPDATE`.

Comment: El valor es $num que varía de 1 en 1, no es estático.

Comment: Creo que faltan detalles en la pregunta. Se supone que tienes un conjunto de datos ya existentes y quieres actualizar una columna de esos datos, ¿cierto? Pues esos datos deben ser **seleccionados** de algún modo, cosa que no haces. Lo que dices de `$num` tampoco lo entiendo. Pon un Ejemplo Mínimo y Verificable de los datos que tienes, explicando el resultado final que esperas obtener.

Comment: He actualizado la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar, necesitas obtener todas las filas mediante un `SELECT` que cumpla los criterios requeridos: el flag, y que `corr` sea `NULL`. En ese `SELECT` obtendremos el `id` que usaremos luego como criterio para cada `UPDATE`.

Luego, lees las filas y vas actualizando cada una con el contador de `$num`. Para ello no necesitas usar dos conexiones, ni preparar la consulta cada vez dentro de un bucle. Precisamente el sentido de las consultas preparadas es trazar un camino una sola vez, no `N` veces, por lo que preparar la misma consulta una y otra vez sería un contra sentido.

También, dado que `bindParam()` vincula *por referencia*<sup>1</sup>, puedes hacer las vinculaciones fuera del bucle una sola vez y los valores que serán seteados cuando ocurra el `execute()` serán los que tenga cada variable en ese momento.

Puede que haga falta un `ORDER BY` en tu consulta `SELECT` si el orden en que los datos deben ser actualizados importa con respecto a alguna columna. No he puesto nada porque no das ningún detalle en ese sentido en el planteamiento de la pregunta.

Así debería funcionar:

```
$bd = new ConectaDB();
$sqlSelect="SELECT id FROM temporal WHERE corr IS NULL AND flg = 'X'";
$stmtSelect=$bd->prepare($sqlSelect);
$stmtSelect->execute();

/*
    OJO a esto: La setencia se prepara una sola vez no N veces
    Y se usa la misma conexión. Nótese que se hace FUERA del bucle
    También las vinculaciones pueden hacer fuera, si usas bindParam
    Agregamos un criterio para diferenciar cada id
*/
$sqlUpdate = "UPDATE temporal SET corr = :num WHERE id = :id";
$stmtUpdate=$bd->prepare($sqlUpdate);    
$id=0;
$num = 0;
$stmtUpdate->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmtUpdate->bindParam(':num', $num, PDO::PARAM_INT);

/*
    Usamos fetchColumn(), pues estamos seleccionado
    solamente el id que es lo que nos interesa para el criterio
*/
while ($id = $stmtSelect->fetchColumn()) {
    $num++;
    $stmtUpdate->execute();
}
```

#### Post-Data

Si este código es para seguir normalizando tus datos, puede que sea necesario replantear tu modelo de datos, y/o resolver esto a nivel de la base de datos, no en PHP. Por ejemplo, si dentro de un tiempo necesites continuar actualizando, tendrás que buscar el último valor del contador para seguir incrementando a partir de ahí. Si esto es así, le estarías tirando a PHP un problema que es de la base de datos, o simplemente resolviendo por programación un error que está en otro nivel (en el diseño del modelo de datos). Esto es como resolver un Bug en tu programa, lo cual puede acarrear serios problemas en varios niveles.

**Notas:**

1. Para más detalles consultar la pregunta: [PHP: ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre bindParam() y bindValue() en PDO?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/59971/29967).

Comment: Actualiza pero pone el total de registros que cumplen la condición. Hice un `var_dump($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM))` y solamente muestra el primer registro.

Comment: @Puntay no entendí tu comentario. Simplemente usé un modo para recorrer cada fila del SELECT e ir actualizando. ¿Te interesa también mostrar algún dato del SELECT o algo por el estilo? ¿A qué te refieres con lo del `var_dump`?

Comment: Cumplen la condición 271 registros. Al ejecutar el código todos los registros que tienen el `flg` ahora tienen en el campo `corr` el valor 271. No debería ser así.

Comment: @Puntay ¿quizá cometiste algún error implementando el código? Edita la pregunta poniendo al final de la misma cómo escribiste el código. Si lo hiciste como te he indicado no debería ocurrir lo que dices, pues `$num` se incrementa cada vez en el `while`

Comment: @Puntay, ya vi cuál podría ser el problema. prueba a cambiar `bindParam` por `bindValue` dentro del bucle `while`.  Además, me di cuenta de que en la respuesta no puse el marcador `:num` entre comillas. Debería quedar así: **`$stmtUpdate->bindValue(':num', $num, PDO::PARAM_INT);`**

Comment: @a-cedano Actualicé la pregunta. Quité el **NULL** de `corr` porque todos son **NULL**.

Comment: @Puntay ¿con `bindValue` no se ha solucionado? Ten en cuenta que si todas las filas adquirieron el mismo valor (271) debes normalizar eso, volviendo a que sean `NULL`  o poniendo temporalmente en el WHERE ese valor.

Comment: Con `bindValue` y colocando que sean `NULL` igual solo coloca el mismo valor (271).Creo que podrías tomar la estructura crear algunos registros de prueba y ver que el código no hace lo que debe hacer. Y estaba pensando: El primer `select` toma los registros que cumplen la condición, quiere decir que son menos registros que el total. Y en el `Update` cómo se restringe a ese grupo?

Comment: Me parece muy extraño que ocurra lo que comentas @Puntay. Haré una prueba con unos pocos datos y te digo.

Comment: @Puntay faltaba en la instrucción `UPDATE` un criterio que identificase cada fila de manera única, era por eso que actualizaba todas las filas indistintamente. Agregando un `WHERE` en el `UPDATE` y modificando las vinculaciones como se indica en la nueva versión de la respuesta funciona. Lo he probado y ahora se actualiza la columna con cada valor incremental.

Comment: Funciona aunque no me queda claro el cambiar `fetch_num` por `fecthcolum`.

Comment: @Puntay PDO tiene varios estilos de obtención de datos, para que uses uno u otro según convenga (puedes consultar esos estilos en el apartado ***fetch style*** de [este enlace](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php)). Otro método de obtención de datos es [`fetchColumn()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php), el cual se suele usar cuando te interesa obtener datos de una columna en específico. Dado que en la nueva versión del código la única columna que interesa es el `id`, he cambiado a `fetchColumn()` para que el código quede optimizado.

Answer (score 0):

La opción correcta, dado que estás alterando registro por registro, es condicionarlo al hecho de que exista algún un registro a modificar. Ejemplo:

Suponiendo que tu método `execute()` devuelve el resultado asociativo del SELECT (y, sino, reemplaza `execute()` por el método correcto):

```php
$bd = new ConectaDB();
$query = $bd->prepare("SELECT * FROM temporal WHERE corr IS NULL AND <CONDICION> LIMIT = 1");
$stmt = $bd->prepare("UPDATE temporal SET corr = :num WHERE id = :id");
$num = 0;

while ($consulta = $query->execute()) {
    $num++;
    $stmt->bindParam(:num, $num, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(:id, $consulta[0]['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

En cada iteración, si `$registro` es un arreglo NO vacío (si se encuentra algún registro sin `corr`), se seguirá ejecutando el while. Tarde o temprano el while se detendrá, pues tus registros no son infinitos y ya todos tendrán un valor asignado a la columna corr.

**NOTAS:**

1. La consulta la debes hacer en cada iteración porque cualquiera de los registros obtenidos previo al while podría dejar de cumplir la condición mientras estás llevando a cabo las actualizaciones. Sobre todo si la tabla es manipulada por varios usuarios a la vez.
   Puedes presumir que son pocos registros a modificar, y que son pocos los registros totales de la tabla, y la tabla la manipulas tu solamente, y cualquier otra condición que busque garantizar que tu lista de registros que cumplen la condición será la misma en dos corridas consecutivas... Pero no es lo correcto. La `<CONDICION>` al final puede ser cualquier cosa, así como el número de filas y el tipo de dato de las columnas.
2. Limitarlo a 1 no es estrictamente necesario, pero así $consulta ocupa menos memoria en cada ejecución. Igual siempre estarás tomando el primer registro.
3. Estoy asumiendo, además, que `id` es la columna que utilizas como índice de tu tabla. Si no lo es, pues reemplaza por el nombre correcto.
   Si no tienes índice, pues tu ejemplo se hará mucho más complejo. Terminarás deseando llevar a cabo todo el proceso en MySQL en lugar de PHP.

Comment: Hay dos errores graves en tu estilo de programar y deberías evitarlos: 1. Conectas dentro de un bucle: `$bd2 = new ConectaDB();` significa que si hay 99999999 elementos conectarás 99999999 veces a la BD. Además, con el objeto `$bd` creado al principio ya basta, no hay que conectar más a la BD. 2. Preparas la consulta `N` veces. No hay necesidad de prepar cada vez. Además de eso, no es como tal un consulta preparada, pues el 2do valor se lo pasas a mano, lo cual no es recomendable. En caso de que sea eso lo que se necesite prepara fuera, poniendo un marcador y haz bind en el bucle.

Comment: ¡Gracias por la corrección!