# ¿Cómo obtengo lastInsertId con clase PDO no estática?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, class

Quiero obtener el **ID** del ultimo **INSERT** a la tabla en la base de datos MySQL, estoy generando la conexión por medio de PDO pero con una clase no estática, les dejo el código:

```
class baseDatosPayBoard {
    // ATRIBUTOS
    private $mysqlServidor;
    private $mysqlBaseDatos;
    private $mysqlUsuario;
    private $mysqlContrasena;
    private $mysqlCharset;
    // METODOS
    public function __construct() {
        $this -> mysqlServidor = '127.0.0.1';
        $this -> mysqlBaseDatos = 'bujic_payboard';
        $this -> mysqlUsuario = 'root';
        $this -> mysqlContrasena = '';
        $this -> mysqlCharset = 'utf8mb4';
    }
    public function conexionBDPayBoard () {
        try {
            $cadenaConexion = 'mysql:host=' . $this -> mysqlServidor . "; dbname=" . $this -> mysqlBaseDatos . "; charset=" . $this -> mysqlCharset;
            $opcionesConexion = [
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
            ];
            $sesionConexion = new PDO($cadenaConexion, $this -> mysqlUsuario, $this -> mysqlContrasena, $opcionesConexion);
            return $sesionConexion;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $errorConexion = $e -> getMessage();
            echo "Error: Fallo al conectar a MYSQL, no se pudo establecer conexión con la base datos de PayBoard! en el servidor: (Información de Error: $errorConexion)";
        }
    }
}
```

Genero el INSERT de la siguiente manera, les dejo el código:

```
try {
    $sentenciaPreparada = $conexionBDPayBoard -> conexionBDPayBoard() -> prepare(
        "INSERT INTO bujic_payboard.convenios (numero_subcredito, nombre_titular, campana_producto, monto_convenio, fecha_convenio, registro_agente, nombre_agente) VALUES (:numeroSubcredito, :nombreTitular, :campanaProducto, :montoConvenio, NOW(), :registroAgente, :nombreAgente)"
    );
    $sentenciaPreparada -> bindParam(':numeroSubcredito', $numeroSubcredito, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sentenciaPreparada -> bindParam(':nombreTitular', $convenioTitular, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sentenciaPreparada -> bindParam(':campanaProducto', $convenioProducto, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sentenciaPreparada -> bindParam(':montoConvenio', $convenioMonto, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sentenciaPreparada -> bindParam(':registroAgente', $usuarioLogueado, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sentenciaPreparada -> bindParam(':nombreAgente', $usuarioNombre, PDO::PARAM_STR);                 
    $sentenciaPreparada -> execute();

    $lastInsertId = $conexionBDPayBoard -> conexionBDPayBoard() -> lastInsertId();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
      $error = $e -> getMessage();
      echo "Ocurrió un problema al registrar la información del convenio, error: $error";
      return;
}
```

He estado investigando un poco en internet, la mayoría explica del modo estático **className::methodName()** ¿Sólo se puede como método estático?

Otra duda que también tengo, ¿Diferencia entre bindParam y bindValue? leí que uno solo se lee al momento del execute() y el otro tipo se almacena. ¿Alguien puede explicarme?

Comment: Esto te marca algún error o qué es lo que falla?

Comment: No me arroja error, solo me lanza un "0", supongo que significa un false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu función `conexionBDPayBoard` crea una conexión diferente cada que lo llamas.

```
 public function conexionBDPayBoard () {
        try {
            ....
            $sesionConexion = new PDO($cadenaConexion, $this -> mysqlUsuario, $this -> mysqlContrasena, $opcionesConexion);
            return $sesionConexion;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            ...
        }
    }
```

tienes que lanzar la consulta sobre la misma conexión

Aquí estás creando una conexión

```
 $sentenciaPreparada = $conexionBDPayBoard -> conexionBDPayBoard() -> prepare(...)
```

Pero aquí estás creando otra diferente.

```
$lastInsertId = $conexionBDPayBoard -> conexionBDPayBoard() -> lastInsertId();
```

Ya que regresas conexiones nuevas, es por ello que generalmente se maneja con clases estáticas, pues la conexión se queda en la clase y no en el objeto.

Para que tu consulta funcione tendrías que hacer.

```
$conexion = $conexionBDPayBoard -> conexionBDPayBoard();
$sentenciaPreparada = $conexion -> prepare(
    "INSERT INTO bujic_payboard.convenios (numero_subcredito, nombre_titular, campana_producto, monto_convenio, fecha_convenio, registro_agente, nombre_agente) VALUES (:numeroSubcredito, :nombreTitular, :campanaProducto, :montoConvenio, NOW(), :registroAgente, :nombreAgente)"
);
... //Resto de tu código
$lastInsertId = $conexion -> lastInsertId();
```

Comment: Ya coloque esa parte del código, pero me indica que es un método indefinido

Comment: Olvidé que la igualas a `prepare` y no a conexión. He modificado mi respuesta y añadido los cambios que tendrías que hacer.

Comment: Ya me funciono el "lastInsertId", maravillosa explicación de igual manera intentare entender lo de clases estáticas ¿Podrías explicarme la diferencia del bindParam y el bindValue?

Comment: Si no deseas usar clases estáticas, te recomiendo que leas acerca de `singleton`. En cuanto a la diferencia de `bindParam` y `bindValue`. Te dejo una pregunta acerca de ello en español con una muy buena explicación. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59971/php-cuál-es-la-diferencia-entre-bindparam-y-bindvalue-en-pdo