# Only variables should be passed by reference

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite

Estoy intentando recibir cierta información de una clase creada en PHP a través de un método interino de la misma clase, donde le paso un parámetro para indicar el tipo de variable de la clase que deseo recibir, y me salta el siguiente error;

> **It Is Not Meant to Be, from Tame Impala [0 / 0]**
>
> **Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\laragon\www\MusicCrawlerLastfmSpotify\index.php on line 114**
>
> **Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\laragon\www\MusicCrawlerLastfmSpotify\index.php on line 115**
>
> **Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\laragon\www\MusicCrawlerLastfmSpotify\index.php on line 116**
>
> **Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\laragon\www\MusicCrawlerLastfmSpotify\index.php on line 117**

En mi código, tengo el archivo donde llamo a la clase **index.php**:

```
        $track = new track($trackitem['name'], $trackitem['artist']['name'], $song_extras["genre"] , $song_extras["decade"] );
        echo $track->getInfo();

        $sql = 'INSERT INTO tracks(name,artist,genre,decade) VALUES(:n,:a,:g,:d);';
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':n', $track->getInfo('name')); // line 114
        $stmt->bindParam(':a', $track->getInfo('artist')); // line 115
        $stmt->bindParam(':g', $track->getInfo('genre')); // line 116
        $stmt->bindParam(':d', $track->getInfo('decade')); // line 117
        $stmt->execute();
```

Y en mi clase, en la misma carpeta root, tengo **Track class**:

```
class track {

  private $name;
  private $artist;
  private $genre;
  private $decade;

  public function __construct($name, $artist, $genre, $decade){
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->artist = $artist;
    $this->genre = $genre;
    $this->decade = $decade;
  }

  public function getInfo($var = '')
  {
     switch($var){
       case 'name': return $this->name; break;
       case 'artist': return $this->artist; break;
       case 'genre': return $this->genre; break;
       case 'decade': return $this->decade; break;
       default: return '<b>'.$this->name.'</b>, from '.$this->artist.' ['.$this->genre.' / '.$this->decade.']<br />';
     }

     return 'Something went wrong.';
  }


}
```

Toda la información es añadida a través de su constructor, sin problemas. Los parámetros extra reciben un 0 cuando está información es desconocida. No hay problema en eso.
Y recibo el error: **Only variables should be passed by reference**

**PDO** no es null, y antes de esta parte del código, se crea una tabla correctamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El segundo parámetro de `bindParam()` debe ser una referencia y le estás pasando una función, de ahí el aviso. La opción que tienes es declarar una variable para cada llamada a la clase y luego incluir dichas variables como segundo parámetro del `bindParam()` o, directamente, usar `bindValue()` en su lugar:

```
// Método 1
$name   = $track->getInfo('name');
$artist = $track->getInfo('artist');
$genre  = $track->getInfo('genre');
$decade = $track->getInfo('decade');

$stmt->bindParam(':n', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':a', $artist);
$stmt->bindParam(':g', $genre);
$stmt->bindParam(':d', $decade);

// Método 2
$stmt->bindValue(':n', $track->getInfo('name'));
$stmt->bindValue(':a', $track->getInfo('artist'));
$stmt->bindValue(':g', $track->getInfo('genre'));
$stmt->bindValue(':d', $track->getInfo('decade'));
```

Comment: Entiendo el punto, gracias, y me gustaría entender porque pasarle una función de esa forma podría ser problemático, pero eso, Sí que esa es la solución.

Comment: @Worstbunny quizá [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/59971/29967) y la respuesta dada te ayude a entender mejor la diferencia y por qué no funciona llamar una función cuando pasas por referencia.

Comment: @Worstbunny, el post que vincula @a-cedano está muy bien y te da la clave: básicamente, tu código alerta de un posible error porque el `bindParam()` solo se revisa cuando se llama a la función `execute()`, por lo que su valor puede haberse modificado entre un punto y otro del código.

Comment: Revisando la pregunta que me anexaste lo comprendo mejor, muchas gracias por vuestras respuestas, la última fue muy aclaratoria.